# Baking textures produces white edges

Tags: texture-baking

(Blender Render)

I'm just practicing baking textures and normals for game development.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting these white edges?

Both my objects are the same size (should that even matter - it seems to). The high poly one has more detail, materials textures and a few bumps in geometry. I want to transpose all the detail onto a simple elongated box, but these white edges appear. I don't get it. They do appear on the low-poly mesh, so I can't ignore them.

[image: Baked texture]

High poly original
[image: Original High Poly]

Low poly with texture applied (not yet done the normal)
[image]

Comment: I have discovered that if the low-poly mesh is slightly bigger, even by a tiny amount, this can happen. But it's ok if the mesh is smaller. This doesn't make much sense to me, as the low-poly mesh is always going to be quite different in dimensions. Do people use cycles instead for baking (with cages etc).